Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error with express
The code is supposed to receive a password and check if the password is matching with the one in  the database and return the result. Instead, it gives the same error no matter what i try.
Express JS:
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Received POST Request!')
    const { Username, Password } = req.body;
    console.log('Received Username:', Username);
    console.log('Received Password:', Password);
    res.send('Received Username: ' + Username);
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1', [Username], (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          //return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      } else {
          if (results.length === 0) {
              //return res.status(404).send('User not found');
          } else {
              const user = results[0];
              const storedPassword = user.password;
              
              if (Password === storedPassword) {
                  //return res.status(200).send('Password Matched');
                  console.log('Passwords matched')
              } else {
                  return res.status(401).send('Incorrect Password');
                  console.log('Passwords didnt match')
              }
          }
      }
  });
});`

I rewrote the code a few times, i commented some responses to see if the issue persists. It recognizes that the passwords are different but has errors returning the result back.

You are doing res.send('Received Username: ' + Username); then you are performing a database query and returning as response in the callback. I would presume the res.send was from earlier testing and you forgot to delete it?

When you call res.send(...), express will dispatch the response back to the client, including all previously set headers and assigned status code. The connection to the client is closed after the response is sent. Check out response.js for how that works under the hood.
When your route is executed, you're almost immediately running this line:
res.send('Received Username: ' + Username);

This is sending the given message as your response to the client (defaulting to a 200 OK response code), and closing the response. Any further .send calls are ignored.
If you wish to fix the problem, simply remove this line (and uncomment your other res.status(..).send(..) calls).
